# PyGTK 2: TreeView is extending out of my window even with scroll bar enabled

Tags: python, scroll, treeview, gtk, pygtk

I have a Gtk window design as follows,

```
-Window
  |- Scroll_Window
    |- TreeView
```

With this design I am able to see tree view inside a scroll window with vertical scroll bar enabled. But the problem is, tree-view is extending out of my window. So if if do down the tree-view using arrow key, the tree-view cursor is going out of view (ie. Going down the actual scroll window).

But if I use my mouse to scroll the tree-view, I am able to see my tree-view data properly.

Expected behavior is on-arrow-down key press, tree-view should scroll by itself with cursor always visible.

**Code:**

```
import sys;
import dbf, gtk, pygtk, gobject;
pygtk.require('2.0');


w = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
w.set_title("TEST");
sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow();
sw.set_border_width(10);
sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

treeView = gtk.TreeView();
listView = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING, gobject.TYPE_STRING);

inData = [["a","1"],["b","bb"],["c","cc"],["d","dd"],["e","ee"],["f","ff"],["g","gg"],["h","hh"],["i","ii"],["j","jj"],["k","kk"],["l","ll"],["n","nn"]];
for nameTinList in inData:
  listIter = listView.append();
  listView.set_value(listIter, 0, nameTinList[0]);
  listView.set_value(listIter, 1, nameTinList[1]);

column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Name", gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0);
column.set_resizable(False);
treeView.append_column(column);
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("DESC", gtk.CellRendererText(), text=1);
column.set_resizable(False);
treeView.append_column(column);

treeView.set_model(listView);
sw.add_with_viewport(treeView);
w.add(sw);
w.show_all();

gtk.main();
w.destroy();
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: GTK+ 2 is probably not scrolling partially visible rows into view; this is normal for GTK+ 2 programs but unusual for Windows programs. GTK+ 3 fixes this behavior. I'm not sure how to fix this in GTK+ 2; sorry.

Comment: I hope the solution should be there for gtk2+ also, since there is lot of applications running with this scroll window

Comment: @andlabs In the OP's example, scrolling with keyboard doesn't work at all, not just for partially visible rows. This is definitely not normal for GTK 2 and is the result (as found by comparing to working examples) of incorrect use of `add_with_viewport`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `sw.add_with_viewport(treeView)` with `sw.add(treeView)`, and scrolling with keyboard will work correctly.

As [the documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkscrolledwindow.html#method-gtkscrolledwindow--add-with-viewport) states, `add_with_viewport` is for child widgets without native scrolling capabilities. For widgets that implement scrolling, such as `gtk.TextView` or `gtk.TreeView`, the `add` method (inherited from `gtk.Container`) should be used.